# Confusion between thread index with CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

lets consider the following statements

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
data[tid]= data [tid] + data[tid+1];
```

suppose tid =0 so :

```
data[0]=data[0]+data[1]
```

My question is in the previous statement we have 2 threads ( thread 0 and thread 1) ? or just one?

Comment: You'll have 2 threads if you launch 2 (or more) threads.  You'll have 1 thread if you only launch 1 thread.  The code you've shown is what *each thread* will execute.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Robert Crovella, the code you show is what each thread executes.

ThreadIdx.x is a read only register which each thread can read to get its own index. It's a equivalent of c#´s:

`Environment.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.`

The amount of thread you have is determined by the way you launch the kernel (the triple bracket thing)

In you case, if you launch you kernel with 1 block of two threads:

```
My kernel<<<1,2>>>(data)
```

You will have thread 0 executing

```
Data[0] += data[1]
```

**While** thread 1 executes

```
Data[1] += data[2]
```

Which created a race condition